# `display: block;` inside `code` tag that is inside `pre` tag creates unwanted new lines and styling is not applied to full length when scrolling

Tags: html, css

I want to make zebra striped code sample with HTML and CSS. If you run the code snippet below you will see that it makes unwanted new lines and styling is not applied to full length of lines when you use the scroll bar. How can I fix this?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <title>Example</title>
 </head>
<style>
 body {
  max-width: 650px;
  margin: 0 auto;
 }
 pre {
  counter-reset: code-line;
  overflow-x: auto;
 }
 code {
  counter-increment: code-line;
  display: block;
 }
 code::before {
  content: counter(code-line) ": ";
 }
 code:nth-child(odd) {
  background-color: #aaa;
 }
</style>
 <body>
  </p>
<pre>
<code>Quisque quis congue lectus. Nullam ornare quis magna sit amet volutpat. Nam quis magna id ex venenatis rutrum.</code>
<code>Quisque quis congue lectus. Nullam ornare quis magna sit amet volutpat.</code>
<code>Quisque quis congue lectus.</code>
</pre>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why are you adding `display: block` ?

Comment: @SameerKhan I added it to apply styling to whole line width, although it didn't quite work when I used the scroll bar. You can just remove `display: block;` and you will see the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with a simple background and you can remove the `display:block`

```css
body {
  max-width: 650px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

pre {
  counter-reset: code-line;
  overflow-x: auto;
  line-height:1.2em;
  background:repeating-linear-gradient(#aaa 0 1.2em,transparent 1.2em 2.4em);
}

code {
  counter-increment: code-line;
}

code::before {
  content: counter(code-line) ": ";
}
```

```html
<pre>
<code>Quisque quis congue lectus. Nullam ornare quis magna sit amet volutpat. Nam quis magna id ex venenatis rutrum.</code>
<code>Quisque quis congue lectus. Nullam ornare quis magna sit amet volutpat.</code>
<code>Quisque quis congue lectus.</code>
</pre>

<pre style="font-size:20px;">
<code>Quisque quis congue lectus. Nullam ornare quis magna sit amet volutpat. Nam quis magna id ex venenatis rutrum.</code>
<code>Quisque quis congue lectus. Nullam ornare quis magna sit amet volutpat.</code>
<code>Quisque quis congue lectus.</code>
</pre>
```

Answer (score 0):

As per the [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/pre) the `<pre>` tag use is to display the text just as it is from the HTML Source file.

The first code tag in your snippet, the sentence exceeds the max-width which you have defined for body, hence the content is overflowing as the sentence is being displayed with the formatting.

To fix this you can use the `white-space` property to wrap the white-space in the element.

```
pre {
    counter-reset: code-line;
    overflow-x: auto;
    white-space: pre-wrap;
}
```